# PHP - REGEX - Match Length

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex :

```
^((?:(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?)\s*function\s+([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+\(\s*(.*)\s*\)\s*
```

to match this string :

```
public function private ($var,Type $typed, $optional = 'option');
```

It works, but when it comes to match this one :

```
public function privateX ($var,Type $typed, $optional = 'option');
```

It fails.

I noticed that when the length of the function's name exceeds 6 chars, it does not match anymore.

Here is the full code :

```
$strA = 'public function 6Chars ($var,Type $typed, $optional = "option");';
$strB = 'public function MoreThan7 ($var,Type $typed, $optional = "option");';

preg_match('!^((?:(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?)\s*function\s+([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+\(\s*(.*)\s*\)\s*!',$strA,$mA);
preg_match('!^((?:(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?)\s*function\s+([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+\(\s*(.*)\s*\)\s*!',$strB,$mB);

print_r($mA);
print_r($mB);
```

My Question is pretty simple : why the second string does not match ?

Comment: Just curious; what are you trying to do (as in, what's your overall goal)? There might be an easier solution to your problem other than regexes.

Comment: try to get all the methods name of a class in a file, without using Reflection, neither php tokenizer.

Comment: I know it's dirty, but i need it to be !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce this in RegexBuddy; both declarations do match. However, the steps needed by the regex engine to arrive at a match double with each character. A function name of 6 characters takes about 100.000 steps of the regex engine, 7 characters 200.000 steps, 8 characters 400.000 steps etc.

Perhaps the regex engine gives up after a certain number of steps?

A possessive quantifier (`++`) cuts down drastically on the number of steps needed by reducing the possible permutations the regex engine has to go through - 50 steps regardless of the length of the function name.

```
!^((?:(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]++)*)?)\s*function\s+([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+\(\s*(.*)\s*\)\s*!
```

The reason for the catastrophic backtracking you're seeing in your regex is this:

```
(?:(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)
```

You are nesting quantifiers, and you've made the spaces optional. Therefore `ABC` can be matched as `ABC`, `A`/`BC`, `AB`/`C` or `A`/`B`/`C`. The number of permutation rises exponentially with every character. You further complicate matters by making the entire group optional (the `?` surrounding the whole thing).

Comment: I reproduced the problem in PHP 5.3 and had error reporting turned on - no reported errors or warnings. I'd be interested in knowing why this fails in PHP

Comment: I didn't know about the possessive quantifier ! But it's that nice !

Comment: There's `preg_last_error()`, which should return an error code if it was indeed hitting a limit on the 'too long' function name.

Comment: I think maybe in case of a memory_limit to low ?  --no, that's not

Answer (score 0):

you just need to enable the `/multiline /m` flag and then it will match both of the lines i tested it confirm below. cheers

[gskinner](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: why would multiline affect it at all? Its one line ... even if it does work, its a non-sensical solution and will probably still break in other edge cases for whatever reason is causing the problem to begin with